# Undo usermod -a -G

Tags: kubuntu, users, crash

I have done

```
sudo usermod -a -G wireshark user
```

And then I have rebooted the system (kubuntu). Now, when entering the password for the GUI, kubuntu crashes and returns to the login screen. However, I can login from the console.

How can I undo this command?

Comment: Can you give the real command?

Comment: @Pilot6 see edit

Comment: This command is not supposed to use any application. It added the `user` user to the `wireshark` group. That could not affect your boot process. It looks like it is not related.

Answer (score 1):

You can undo it by

```
sudo deluser user wireshark
```

but it is not related to your login loop problem.

For **Rinzwind** from `man deluser`

```
deluser [options] user group

 ....

Remove a user from a specific group
       If  called  with  two  non-option arguments, deluser will remove a user
       from a specific group.
```

--

```
pilot6@Pilot6:~$ sudo deluser pilot6 vboxusers
Removing user `pilot6' from group `vboxusers' ...
Done.
```

Comment: are you sure? I would assume 1 of those should be a group(?)

Comment: `wireshark` is a group.

Comment: but here you remove a user wireshark ;-)

Comment: No, look into `man deluser`.

Comment: `deluser --group [options] group` it says in my man You are misreading the manual: you need an option -G or --group for deluser to delete a group

Comment: Look below. I use this command ant it works.

Comment: +1 . . . or you could use `gpasswd --delete <user> <group>` which is less confusing I think